# Add a custom field to Contact Form 7 tag

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'd like add custom field to cf7 tag. ( see image )
Is there any add_filter hook that i can use for it ?
Please help me.

Thankk
[image: Example Image]

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on what this tag should be ? there are some tags that are not well documented , and if not - I know some ways of doing that but It will depend on the Custom field itself ..

Comment: Hi Obmerk Kronen, and thank for your response. i wanna insert a text field in every tag to pass a value to shortcode. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understood that - but what is the value ? like said above, some CF7 tags already exist ( albeit with poor documentation) and do not need a special hook.. like `sender IP`, `post_ID`, `sent_time` , `unique_id` and actually many others...

Comment: i need a text field where user can insert text and this value is in shortcode as a data-attribute. For example i insert as value in my custom field "Hello" and when the shortcode i rendered i can see [code]<input type="text" data-attribute="Hello" value="" ecc ecc/>[code]

Comment: ok, I have done it before, let me dig some code out of the repos ..

Comment: Wow, perfect.. Thanks !

Comment: @Francesco I cannot find the plugin can you please provide me with the link to download that plugin?

Answer (score 15):

well, I may have misunderstood what you want , but :

this is how CF7 register the text fields shorttags :

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_shortcode_text' );

function wpcf7_add_shortcode_text() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode(
        array( 'text', 'text*', 'email', 'email*', 'url', 'url*', 'tel', 'tel*' ),
        'wpcf7_text_shortcode_handler', true );
}
```

Note that the hook is `wpcf7_init` for the function `wpcf7_add_shortcode()` so , if we make our own example :

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_shortcode_hello' );



function custom_add_shortcode_hello() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'custom_hello_shortcode_handler' ); // "helloworld" is the type of the form-tag
}
```

And  then the callback handler

```
function custom_hello_shortcode_handler( $tag ) {
    return 'hello world ! ';
}
```

now if you will add this in the form

```
CF7 say : [helloworld]
```

you should see

```
CF7 say : hello world !
```

If you want to use normal form tags , note that the available default types are :

```
text, text*, email, email*, tel, tel*, url, url*, textarea ,textarea* , number, number*, range and range* , date , date*,checkbox, checkbox*, radio, select and select* , file , file*, captchac ,captchar, quiz , acceptance, submit;
```

Now, I wrote all this, because as far as I know ( and I might be wrong ) there is no filter for the HTML form for an already existing tag that are defined in the function  `wpcf7_tg_pane_text_and_relatives()` in `modules/text.php`

, but what you can do is remove the default tag ( for example text ) by using `wpcf7_remove_shortcode( $tag );` and then add your own adapting the example above to your need by creating a new one ( for example text )

That being said , I am not really sure yet what and why you want this ( you really did not explained the goal, just the way ) because IMHO , and after a lot of CF7 custom plugins that I wrote , I really do not understand why not just create a new tag , which is easier and more constructed .

But then again, I might be wrong .

Comment: Upvoted since this answer includes some useful info, and OP's original question was very vague...

Comment: @fazen I cannot find the plugin can you please provide me with the link to download that plugin?

Comment: wpcf7_add_shortcode() is deprecated and its alternative is: wpcf7_add_form_tag()
https://contactform7.com/2016/12/03/contact-form-7-46